# How can I exclude the first character of a paragraph from the selection?

Tags: regex, select, paragraph, negative-lookbehind

This selects the content of a paragraph.

```
^(.*)$
```

This additionally selects the selected number of beginning characters of a paragraph, but does not exclude them.

```
^[^.*{1}](.*)$
```

Comment: You are using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^.*{1}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of regex you're using, you could use \K to reset the match after the first character, for example:

```
^.\K.*$
```

If you can't use \K, you should be able to use a negative look-ahead to ignore the first character of the string:

```
(?!^.).*$
```

`(?!something)` is a negative look-ahead which ensures that whatever follows that matches what's in the parentheses is NOT included in the match. `^.` is the character immediately following the start of the string.